# Is it possible get apex collection from another application in apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, oracle-apex

I have application in Oracle Apex where I create collection. I need data from this collection in other Oracle Apex application. I tried to call SQL function:

```
FUNCTION TestColl RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    tmp number;
    v_workspace_id apex_workspaces.workspace_id%type;
    v_work_id NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    apex_application.g_flow_id := 100; --Application Id with collection I need
    v_work_id :=APEX_UTIL.FIND_SECURITY_GROUP_ID (p_workspace=>'XXX');
    apex_util.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id => v_work_id);
    apex_custom_auth.set_session_id(p_session_id => '00000000'); --some session id
    commit;
    SELECT COUNT(*) into tmp FROM APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE collection_name='C_COLLECTION_NAME';
    return to_char(tmp);
END TestColl;
```

This function return 0 but in IDE it return some.

This two applications have different database schemes with grants.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session state is tied to both applications and sessions (except for application items that have their Scope set to Global). Without built-in support for "scope" at the collection level, I can't see how you'd make this work without doing something really hacky (you were starting down that road already). Without such support, just use your own tables.

Collection data is stored in traditional heap tables, so that's easy enough. I recommend adding a SESSION_ID column to the table and using shared authentication between the apps (set cookie values in authentication to be the same). Then you just have to create a job to delete data for expired sessions.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way of determining expired sessions? apex_session doesn't seem to provide that capability unless you try to attach to each session in your heap table.

Comment: Well, if you don’t see them in apex_session, then I believe it’s safe to assume the are expired. You may have some already expired sessions lingering around in there, but they will go away eventually.